# How to create a regular grid of triangles correctly?

Tags: opengl, terrain, opentk

I am trying to create an terrain using opentk/opengl.

I have a problem with the VBO/IBO.
I think a picture of the problem is the best way to show it: 
[image: the problem]

I dont understand why the last triangle of a row connects to the first vertices of the row.

Here is the code:

```
int mapSize = 7;
    void CreateVertexBuffer()
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(mapSize + 1) * (mapSize + 1)];
        short[] indices = new short[ ((mapSize)*(mapSize)) * 6];


        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize + 1 ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize + 1 ; y++)
            {
                int li_offset = x * (mapSize + 1) + y;
                vertices[li_offset] = new Vector3(x / 4.0f, 0 , y / 4.0f);
            }
        }
        int index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize ; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mapSize ; y++)
            {
                indices[index + 0] = (short)( x * (mapSize + 1) + y);
                indices[index + 1] = (short)(indices[index + 0] + mapSize + 2);
                indices[index + 2] = (short)(indices[index + 0] + mapSize + 1);

                indices[index + 3] = (short)(indices[index + 0]);
                indices[index + 4] = (short)(indices[index + 0] + 1);
                indices[index + 5] = (short)(indices[index + 0] + 2);

                index += 6;
            }
        }
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(vertices.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                               vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out ibo);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ibo);
        GL.BufferData<short>(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(indices.Length * sizeof(short) ),
                               indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    }
```

How can I make the last row of triangles properly formed like all the others?

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but if it's using triangle strips for rendering you might need to use a degenerate triangle at the end of each row, and zig-zag down. So if you numbered your quads in a 4xN it would go like 0,1,2,3, 7,6,5,4...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after bug-searching for a while i came up with this, which works just fine.

```
 void CreateVertexBuffer()
    {
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[mapSize*mapSize];

        short[] indices;

        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < mapSize; z++)
            {
                vertices[x * mapSize + z] = new Vector3(x/10.0f,1.0f,z/10.0f); 
            }
        }       

        indices = new short[mapSize * mapSize * 6];
        int index = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < mapSize ; x++)
        {
           for (int z = 0; z < mapSize-1; z++)
           {
                int offset = x * mapSize + z;
                indices[index] = (short)(offset + 0);
                indices[index + 1] = (short)(offset + 1);
                indices[index + 2] = (short)(offset + mapSize);
                indices[index + 3] = (short)(offset + 1);
                indices[index + 4] = (short)(offset + mapSize + 1);
                indices[index + 5] = (short)(offset + mapSize);
                index += 6;
            }
        }

        GL.GenBuffers(1, out vbo);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
        GL.BufferData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(vertices.Length * Vector3.SizeInBytes),
                               vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.GenBuffers(1, out ibo);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, ibo);
        GL.BufferData<short>(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer,
                               new IntPtr(indices.Length * sizeof(short) ),
                               indices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    }
```